# How to call a function in Fortran that is defined in a separate file?

Tags: function, linker, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile some really old code (1986 and before). This code references an external function. Today's compilers ask for far more code to make this work. And I keep failing.
I now created a small hello world program, which demonstrates the problem.

hello.for

```
  PROGRAM hello
    USE func        
    PRINT *, "Hello World!"
    PRINT *, f ()    
  END PROGRAM hello
```

func.for

```
  MODULE func
    PUBLIC f
  CONTAINS
    FUNCTION f () 
        f='Hello Func'
    END FUNCTION
  END MODULE
```

This has not only one, but two problems:

- How do I define the return type? Docs tell `<type> FUNCTION <function>` or `FUNCTION <function> () <type>::<something>` , but neither works.
- How do I make the linker find the function?

`gfortran -c func.for` works (if I use the default return type real) and creates a mod file but linking does not work

```
$ gfortran  hello.for 
/tmp/ccHNzcXA.o: In function `MAIN__':
hello.for:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `__func_MOD_f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`__func_MOD_f` is *not* contained in the mod file, but in the o file there is `func.for__func_MOD_f`.

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: In your specific simple example, you simply need to put the `module..end module` before the `program..end program` statement. In a more complex example - perhaps with different files in different folders - you have several choices. The simplest thing to do is provide them all to your compiler, such as `gfortran file1.for file2.for`.

Comment: It's also unclear what problem you're having when declaring the return type. Can you expand on your sample code in that case?

Comment: It's two separate files. I cannot wrap the program with the module. and I already tried passing both files on the command line. did  not work.

Comment: `f='Hello Func'` does not work because the default return type is REAL. how do I set CHARACTER?

Comment: Does casey's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues, the delcaration of `f` and properly linking the module.

First, compiling the module yields the error:

```
% gfortran -c func.f
func.f:5:8:

       f='Hello Func'
        1
Error: Can't convert CHARACTER(1) to REAL(4) at (1)
```

This error is due to implicit typing of `f` and an incompatible assignment.  Fixing this is simple, declare `f` explicitly as a `character` instead of an implicit type. Add:

```
character(len=30) :: f
```

to the function and now your module compiles.  Here is the modified module:

```
  MODULE func
  PUBLIC f
  CONTAINS
  FUNCTION f ()
  character(len=30) :: f
  f='Hello Func'
  END FUNCTION
  END MODULE
```

---

Your second problem is linking.  Your command:

```
gfortran  hello.for
```

fails because you did not specify the module object.  If you already compiled the module you would specify:

```
gfortran hello.for func.o
```

if you were compiling them both at the same time you would do:

```
gfortran -o hworld func.for hello.for
```

if you are compiling everything individually:

```
gfortran -c func.for
gfortran -c hello.for
gfortran -o hworld hello.o func.o
```

Any of these will compile and run:

```
% ./hworld 
 Hello World!
 Hello Func
```

---

If you are modernizing your code, it would also be worth adding `implicit none` to avoid any implicit typing and declaring explicit variables for everything.  e.g.:

```
module func
  implicit none
contains
function f 
  implicit none
  character(len=30) :: f
  f='Hello Func'
end function f
end module func
```

and

```
program hello
  use func
  implicit none        
  print *, "Hello World!"
  print *, f ()    
end program hello
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not make clear enough: this are two separate files. And I want them to stay separate since there are 10 other programs that refer to this module.

Comment: One compiles other files individually using `-c`, for example `gfortran -c func.for`

Comment: Thank you very much. Hours of trying come to an end. Where exactly do I put the `implicit none`?

Comment: @JPT after any `use` statements and before any variable declarations in any scoping unit.